# No apps will open except Internet Explorer

Tags: 8.1, apps, nokia-lumia-630

I have a Nokia Lumia 630 with Windows Phone 8.1.

Since last night, the only app that will open is Internet Explorer. When I try to open Phone, Messaging, or any other app, it just flashes back to the start screen. Also I can not call out and my phone book seems to have disappeared as when someone calls in only their phone number shows up.

My phone has been low on space so I have deleted multiple apps such as games, Music app and all music and other apps that I don't use. It now says I have space but still won't open anything I actually need - phone book, dialer, text messaging, pictures, etc. I haven't tried a hard reset yet as I was hoping to be able to at least save the pictures if nothing else.

The only thing that will open is the internet explorer. When I try to open dialer,text, or anything else it just flashes back to the start screen. It started last night. My phone had been low on space so I have deleted multiple apps such as games, music app and all music and other apps that I don't use. It now says I have space but still wont open anything I actually need. Phone book, dialer,text, pictures etc.. I haven't hard reset it yet was hoping to be able to atleast save the pictures if none else.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide more information. What phone do you have? What version of Windows Phone is it running (settings -> about)? What exactly happens when you try to open the Phone, Messaging or other apps? Does this occur with any app? When did it start?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Have you tried a hard reset?

Comment: If you want to recover your photos, you should be able to connect your phone to a PC with a USB cable and copy the photos over. As for the problem itself, is your phone software up-to-date? You can check in Settings -> Phone update.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Nokia Lumia 630. It won't open any apps and just goes back to the start page. I have tried a soft restart but that didn't work. I don't really want to do a factory reset as I will lose my contacts and I can't open my contacts to write the details down. I can't even back up as the phone won't let me.